# Missing objects when opening old file in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, layers

I just got a updated to blender 2.8 and my objects that were in hidden layers are gone now, the collection layer tells me that they are in the scene but I cant unhide them also the collection is grayed out as well.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's been hidden in the viewport in 2.79 you can make it visible in 2.8 by going to the Outliner.

[image]

Click on the filter icon and under *Restriction toggles* select *Disable in Viewport* (screen icon).

[image]

You can now set the collection back to being visible by clicking on the screen icon behind the collection.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this is so helpful it also gave me the solution for another problem I had :D

Answer (score 1):

I also have such a problem, but I solved it.
Here is what you need to do:
Right-click on “Collection 1” -> “Visibility” -> “Enable in viewport”.
That's it, now hidden layers will become active.

P.S. I also noticed that the files saved in the new version of the program, unfortunately, do not open in older versions of the program. The blender just closes when you try to open new files. No version compatibility, this is sad.

It seems like I was typing a message for too long, they got ahead of me :)

Comment: I think the blender devs had to make some tough decisions in order to make things better in the future, unfortunately this means some difficulties for users during the transition.  So maybe not so sad, just a necessary step that nobody enjoys taking, but will be glad they have.