# Can't select or interact with downloaded objects unless in edit mode

Tags: mesh, objects, selection-tools, collections

need some help.
I downloaded this free car model, and everything worked great until i tried to move it around.

It is made of many parts so I selected everything with <kbd>A</kbd> and tried to rotate the whole thing.

Problem is, **4 objects** (namely the 4 rims of the wheels) stayed put and didn't do a thing.

I can see the meshes, but I cant select/box select them. I discovered that pressing "A" does not select them at all, and when selecting them from the collections (blender 2.8), i still can't move them.

I also tried Parenting them to other objects but with no result.

The only thing I can apparently do, is go into Edit mode which actually highlights the mesh normally.

I tried merging the mesh with other objects, duplicating and splitting it into another mesh, but nothing has worked so far.

Am i missing some obscure setting that prohibits me from interacting or is it an actual issue with the mesh/file?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing objects when opening old file in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146983/missing-objects-when-opening-old-file-in-blender-2-8)

Answer (score 1):

simply **export** the **blender 2.79** file as an **.FBX** file to **Blender 2.80**

[image]

blender 2.79b or earlier are **not 100% compatible** with 2.80 or later, **you should use another format** such as **OBJ** (object) or **FBX** which is the one that works best for me personally

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: do not forget to mark the answer as accepted so that they know that your question was solved