# Can't show collections after migrating from 2.7

Tags: collections

I've been working on a large model in Blender 2.7, and I split it into layers to manage it better. Now I've updated to 2.83, and I've learnt about layers being replaced by collections. However, when I open my file in 2.83, I get this in the Outliner:

[image: Outliner showing the list of my collections]

Even though all collections have the open eye, only the first one is visible, and the View submen only shows the first one:

[image: View submenu showing only the first collection]

Is this something related to my file being migrated to 2.83? How do I get all my objects back again?

Comment: Maybe when converting hidden layers it set them to disabled in viewport option. Note that by default in 2.8 not all icons are shown which affect displaying in viewport and render (that's kinda gotcha but if you don't like it edit your startup file). To enable open Filter popup in the Outliner header and choose  Disable in Viewports as well as Disable in Renders filters too

Comment: @MrZak That was it! Please write an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Don't leave because I'll have to post another question :)

Comment: I was going to let you answer instead but everything is already written somewhere and answered - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146983/missing-objects-when-opening-old-file-in-blender-2-8. As well as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150917/missing-objects-from-old-blender-in-2-8-hidden-in-2-79b-and-lost-in-2-8

Comment: Possible duplicate [Missing objects when opening old file in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146983/missing-objects-when-opening-old-file-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Yes that's a duplicate. I'm sorry, I thought I had searched well for it, but I was wrong. Thank you!